# Regular Expressions (Regex) e-mail validation

Tags: c#, regex, validation, email

A textbox in a WinForm I have created is for e-mail.
I'm checking the validation of the e-mail format.  The string seems to be ignoring the "." condition?  According to my test, it runs:

1. abcdef   - Not valid  (Correct)
2. abcdef@gmail    - valid     (Incorrect)
3. abcdefgmail.com      - Not valid     (Correct)
4. abcdef@gmail.com     - Valid   (Correct)

***Code Snippet:***

```
Regex RX = new Regex("^[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}~](\\.?[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}~])*@[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*(\\.[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*)+$");
```

Comment: You need to escape the dot using `\.`

Comment: The reason it's "ignoring" the `.` is that that's a wildcard in regex. Escape it as follows: `\.`

Comment: Validating an email-address using regular expressions is a bit more complicated than your implementation here. Your expression will also fail for addresses having dots or hyphens in them, both of which are - among others - valid characters in email addresses. Please see also this question for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/1521227

Comment: By the way, there are many valid email addresses that will be rejected by your regex.

Comment: Why are you limiting the user-part to 20 and the top-level-domain-part to 3 letters? Thus you reject many many adresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a backslash in front of the dot:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$"
```

Without that `\`, `.` will match any character.

Comment: @David Faber                it's saying that \ is "unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: @JoshM - either use a double `\ `, or use a "verbatim string literal" by ading a `@` before the leading `"`

Comment: @HansKesting Thank you.  This is my new regex expression (I editied it at the top).  Seems to work pretty well.